# Resize window so text dont move

Tags: html, css

Lock text and tables when resizing window. Could someone show me example.

Comment: i think giving them fixed fixels height and width using style shall do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width to your body or content container:

```
body { width:960px; }
```

That will stop it from reformatting the flow of the text when the window size is smaller than the width specified.  The same goes for the table.